# SQLCMD - ERROR: "Shared Memory Provider: No process is on the other end of the pipe."

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a script via sqlcmd. I am using window authentication.

[image]

I tried the following:

1. Open the SQL Server Configuration Manager on the SQL Server.
2. Expand SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for [Instance name]
3. Makes sure that Shared Memory, Named Pipes, and TCP/IP are enabled.
4. If any of the above was disabled, enable them.
5. Restart SQL Server Services to apply the changes.

I also tried to ensure that SQL Server security is set to both Windows and SQL Authentication. I am not sure what else to try. I am sure that the Windows user has permission for the database I am using.

I also tried creating a SQL User and set the Server security properties to 'Windows Authentication + SQL Authentication

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `RANCOR` the name of your own computer, or is it instead a different machine hosting the SQL Server instance? If they're two different computers try using `-S tcp:RANCOR\HARDAC` or, on your own computer, open the SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager tool and adjust the SQL Server Native Client protocols (both 32-bit and 64-bit settings) such that the TCP/IP protocol has the highest priority.

Comment: If it's your own PC then don't enter `-S servername` at all

Comment: I should have been more specific. I am trying to load this on my local computer. I changed the command to `sqlcmd -i "C:\Temp\script.sql"` but I am getting this error and few other:     
`Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].`

Comment: I think the error message is bad insofar as I think it's telling you that *all* attempts to connect (regardless of protocol) failed. Changing the allowed login protocols or adjusting users/logins is not going to help here - the error represents a fundamental lack of ability for your client to even connect to the instance.